Are “checkbook control” or “truly self-directed” TFSAs a thing in Canada?
Context
In the United States, it's possible — albeit pretty uncommon — to form a corporation wholly owned by a tax-advantaged retirement account, so long as it doesn't invest in any forbidden asset classes or engage in “self-dealing” such as buying property from yourself or relatives, or taking physical custody of precious metals owned by the LLC; this is done to allow that corporation's profits to be completely free of income tax while in the retirement account. (NerdWallet, Forbes, and Wikipedia all have pretty good articles about this.)
This is referred to as a “self-directed IRA” (SDIRA) — sometimes a “truly self-directed IRA” or “checkbook control LLC” to differentiate it from marketing by non-SDIRA retirement plan administrators that merely happen to provide a wide array of stock choices or a few extra asset classes — and because it requires more paperwork on the part of the plan administrator/sponsor and much more caution on the part of the participant, it's generally not available from discount brokerages or employer-sponsored plans, and has to be got from a plan administrator that specializes in that (such as Entrust Group, RocketDollar, or UDirect).
In Canada, Income Tax Folio S3-F10-C1, Qualified Investments §Small business investments does not specify that the corporations held by a TFSA (“Tax-Free Savings Account”, functionally the Canadian equivalent of a Roth IRA) must be publicly traded, only that they be domestic:

1.56 A share of a specified small business corporation is a qualified investment for an RRSP, RESP, RRIF, FHSA or TFSA if the share is not a prohibited investment for the plan. …

specified small business corporation, at any time, means a corporation (other than a cooperative corporation) that would, at that time or at the end of the last taxation year of the corporation that ended before that time, be a small business corporation if the expression “Canadian-controlled private corporation” in the definition small business corporation in subsection 248(1) of the Act were read as “Canadian corporation (other than a corporation controlled at that time, directly or indirectly in any manner whatever, by one or more non-resident persons)”. (société déterminée exploitant une petite entreprise)

small business corporation, at any particular time, means, subject to subsection 110.6(15), a particular corporation that is a Canadian-controlled private corporation all or substantially all of the fair market value of the assets of which at that time is attributable to assets that are … used principally in an active business carried on primarily in Canada by the particular corporation or by a corporation related to it, …



Question
Does anything like an SDIRA LLC exist in Canada, specifically for a TFSA?
I ask because I cannot find even a scrap of information online about people actually exercising the option described in S3-F10-C1 ¶1.56. Not one article, not one advertisement, and not even a blurb on an estate planning website that suggests they'll help you set up such an account.
So... how do Canadian citizens usually go about doing the ¶1.56 “private equity retirement” thing?

Please spell out all acronyms at least once.

If it turns out that this question's answer hinges on my reading of Canadian law, rather than mere Canadian investor habits or business service popularity, it may be appropriate to migrate it back to its original spot on Law Stack Exchange.

It seems to me that a corporation wholly owned by (your) tax retirement account is a prohibited investment according to the link you give, because you own it all.

Nothing in these articles is about forming any corporations. Corporations would require officers, directors, end employees, you'd have to have at least one of these roles, which would make it a prohibited transaction and invalidate the whole IRA.

TFSAs are not designed to be shelters for your corporate doings. They are designed for small investors to stash small amounts of money away tax free in well-regulated and well-understood relatively risk free investments. Allowing you to put your own businesses in the TFSA open them up to all sorts of misuse including (but not limited to) the trick where you sell your corporate TFSA a million dollar asset for $1, thus hiding a million dollars in your TFSA, beating the investment limits. Also I don't think "indirect owner" comes into it. You own all the contents of your TFSA.

@DJClayworth Isn't the misuse you describe already prohibited with the prohibition on “arm's-length” dealing in the second bulletpoint of ¶1.59, cf. the U.S.'s prohibition on “self-dealing”?

@JamesTheAwesomeDude That's a US law. But in any case it's not "self-dealing" if it's your buddy's asset, especially if it goes "unexpectedly" from $1000 to $1000000.

The thing you are describing is not possible with a TFSA.
First, note that a TFSA is not an IRA equivalent. It's intended for the average investor to be able to save a relatively small amount of money without paying tax on the income generated. It's not specifically intended for retirement savings. There are RRSPs for that.
The intention is that TFSAs should only contain straightforward, well-understood relatively low risk investments. They are not intended as a tax haven for corporate activity. As such there are investments that it is prohibited to own in a TFSA. Real estate is one. Another is corporations and other entities that you control.

More specifically, a share of a corporation is a prohibited investment for a plan if either of the following conditions is met:

the controlling individual of the plan is a specified shareholder of the corporation (generally a taxpayer who owns directly or indirectly 10% or more of any class of shares of the corporation, taking into account non-arm’s-length and certain other holdings)
the controlling individual of the plan does not deal at arm’s length with the corporation


This would seem to prevent the TFSA "investing" in a corporation that you control.
Most TFSAs are "self directed" in that the owner can choose exactly what investments to make (within the legal restrictions).

So if the TFSA's controlling individual / beneficiary counts as an “indirect owner” of the assets it holds, then that would imply a TFSA can't own 10% or more of any corporation?

Yes, that is my understanding.
